# Interval in which a function's roots lie.

Tags: analysis, functions, numerical-methods, roots, interval-arithmetic

I have this problem:

> The root of the function $f(x)=\cos(x) -x +2 $, lies in
>
> a. [0,2]
>
> b. [1,2]
>
> c. [-1,1]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Have you take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)? Try to write your your questions in a clear way and show what you have tried. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can also find a simple tutorial to write in LaTex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f(x)=\cos(x)-x+2$ is continuous on $[-1,2]$ as it is the sum of three continuous functions. Therefore, we can apply the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

The intermediate value theorem states that if a function $f(x)$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and if $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$ (or vice-versa), then there is some third point $c$ with $a<c<b$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Therefore, you should find the value of $f(x)$ on the endpoints of the three intervals

- $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ where $[a,b]=[0,2]$
- $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ where $[a,b]=[1,2]$
- $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ where $[a,b]=[-1,1]$

The interval where $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$ (or vice-versa) is where you will have a root of $f(x)$. In your case, two of the intervals contain a root of $f(x)$.

Comment: Very detailed and clearly explained, thank you!

Comment: ok but i still think one of the intervals among a and b is a better choice than the other? what say?

Comment: Neither one is better. Both contain at least one root of $f(x)$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Just plug in the upper and lower limits of the range and observe if there's a change in sign in the values of the function.

For example, $f(0) =3$, $f(2) \approx -0.416 $

where $f(x) = \cos x -x +2$

Comment: I know, there is a change in sign in the values of function in both a and b intervals. So which one is the correct option?

Comment: There are 2 correct options...

Comment: Yeah i figured as much, but i still think one of them is a better choice than the other?